# Cholesky factorization: Why is MATLAB is way faster than Python/R

Tags: python, r, matlab, lapack, intel-mkl

I'm wondering why MATLAB is so much faster than Python and R at cholesky factorization, even if at least Python is also using Intel's MKL.

```
MATLAB:        Python:         R:
----------------------------------------------
8.0034e-4 s    30.7093e-4 s    105.0849e-4 s    
100.00 %       383.70 %        1313.00 %
```

As an example I used a MATLAB generated matrix:

```
matrix = gallery('moler',600)
```

(600 because the matrix in my actual code has this size)

and stored it as .csv file.

**Code:**

MATLAB:

```
filename = './matrix.csv';
delimiter = ',';

formatSpec = [repmat('%f', 1,600) '%[^\n\r]'];

fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'EmptyValue' ,NaN, 'ReturnOnError', false);

fclose(fileID);

x = [dataArray{1:end-1}];

clearvars filename delimiter formatSpec fileID dataArray;

t=zeros(1000, 1);
for i=1:length(t)
    tic;
    chol(x,'lower');
    t(i)=toc;
end;

disp(['Mean: ' num2str(mean(t)) [' s']])
>> test
Mean: 0.00080034 s
```

Python:

```
import time
import numpy as np

x = np.loadtxt('./matrix.csv', delimiter=',')
time_elapsed = np.zeros(1000)
for i in range(0, len(time_elapsed)):
    t = time.time()
    np.linalg.cholesky(x)
    time_elapsed[i] = time.time() - t
print('Mean: '+str(time_elapsed.mean())+" s")

Python ./test.py
Mean: 0.00307093310356 s
```

R:

```
library(readr)
library(tictoc)
x <- read_csv("./matrix.csv", col_names = FALSE)
tic.clearlog()
for (i in 0:1000)
{
  tic(i)
  chol(x)
  toc(log = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
}
log.lst <- tic.log(format = FALSE)
tic.clearlog()
timings <- unlist(lapply(log.lst, function(x) x$toc - x$tic))
print(paste0("Mean: ", mean(timings), " s"))

source('./test.R')
[1] "Mean: 0.0105084915084904 s"
```

**System Info:**

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2643 v3 @ 3.40GHz, 6 Cores HT enabled, 64 GB Ram

OS:

```
uname -a
Linux 4.8.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.15-2 (2017-01-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

MATLAB:

```
version
9.1.0.441655 (R2016b)

version -java
Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode

version -blas
Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 11.3.1 Product Build 20151021 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications, CNR branch AVX2

version -lapack
Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 11.3.1 Product Build 20151021 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications, CNR branch AVX2
Linear Algebra PACKage Version 3.5.0
```

R:

```
version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.2                         
year           2016                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        71607                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
nickname       Sincere Pumpkin Patch
```

Python:

```
conda --version
conda 4.3.11

python --version
Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
np.version.full_version
'1.11.2'

np.__config__.show()
blas_mkl_info:
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    library_dirs = ['~/anaconda3/lib']
    include_dirs = ['~/anaconda3/include']
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
lapack_mkl_info:
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    library_dirs = ['~/anaconda3/lib']
    include_dirs = ['~/anaconda3/include']
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
lapack_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    library_dirs = ['~/anaconda3/lib']
    include_dirs = ['~/anaconda3/include']
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
blas_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    library_dirs = ['~/anaconda3/lib']
    include_dirs = ['~/anaconda3/include']
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

mkl.get_version_string()
'Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 11.3.3 Product Build 20160413 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications'
```

Comment: Matlab stores the data internally in a flat array that's likely consistent with sending directly to MKL.  I suspect (not sure) that the other two need to do a data copy from their "native" format to something compatible with MKL. Despite its hard-to-understand popularity, Python is not an especially good language for any serious computing. (Being free seems to be all it really has going for it.)  R has its niche role, but it's also not made for tons of speed.

Comment: Because..... whoever programmed it did a better job? This is probably the best answer you probably are going to get.

Comment: @Brick not sure about R, numpy uses 1D arrays internally also.

Comment: @AnderBiguri It's not enough for the array to 1D.  It has to be sorted in the right order.  Just pulled docs and will try to write an answer with more detail soon...

Comment: @Brick I am aware, but I'd be surprised if either MATLAB or python have multiple permutations for each time they call a library function

Comment: Matlab is optimized all one way.  The python docs are explicit that they support multiple orderings, which it apparently has to handle on the fly.  Not sure about R. @AnderBiguri

Comment: @Brick: No, the orderings are handled separately.  Each array is flagged with the particular ordering it uses.

Comment: @TheBlackCat I think that's the problem.  See my answer. In order to be fast, there should be only one possible ordering (and therefore no need for a flag).  It still has to conform to ordering requirements when it passes to external libraries, and nympy has chose a default ordering that's not consistent with the linear algebra routines. I agree that each specific array is in only one ordering that's marked by a flag in meta data of the array.

Comment: @Brick: see my comment on your answer.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#BLAS , https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#LAPACK with that you can use in `R` the same libraries for linear algebra as Matlab

Comment: Did anyone come with a faster method in the end ?
I am looking at trying to use nvidia CUDA's methods in Python as a last resort.